# Checking if two values in Query are the same, makes Query very slow

Tags: mysql, sql

### My Goal:

A Query, which provides all provinces, in which a building is constructing.

### My Problem:

As soon as I make sure that every building is compared to the same building (comparing upgrade_id) the Query takes forever. Without the last part of the where statement it takes 1 sec, which is totally fine.

### Table Setup

Provinces change from time to time and are saved every day with their current timestamp.
The province_has_building table contains the many to many relationship from provinces to buildings. Every building has their upgrade_id -> type of building and their health.

### Query

```sql
SELECT 
a.province_id,
a.province_location_id, 
a.current_time, 
b.current_time,
a_b.upgrade_id, 
b_b.upgrade_id, 
(a_b.health - b_b.health) as health
FROM province a
JOIN province b
ON b.province_location_id = a.province_location_id and b.current_time between TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(a.current_time, INTERVAL 3600 * 24 + 500 SECOND)) and TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(a.current_time, INTERVAL 3600 * 24 - 500 SECOND))

-- Day 1 Building
JOIN province_has_building a_pb
on a_pb.province_id = a.province_id
JOIN building a_b
on a_pb.building_id = a_b.building_id


-- Day 2 Building
JOIN province_has_building b_pb
on b_pb.province_id = b.province_id
JOIN building b_b
on b_pb.building_id = b_b.building_id                                                                            

WHERE a.game_id = 5547382 and a_b.upgrade_id = b_b.upgrade_id
```

### Explain

| table | type | possible_keys | key | ref | rows | filtered | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | ref | PRIMARY,fk_province_game1_idx | fk_province_game1_idx | const | 237387 | 100.00 |  |
| a_pb | ref | PRIMARY,fk_building_has_province_province1_idx,fk_building_has_province_building1_idx | fk_building_has_province_province1_idx | testing.a.province_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| a_b | eq_ref | PRIMARY, SECONDARY | PRIMARY | testing.a_pb.building_id | 1 | 100.00 |  |
| b_b | ref | PRIMARY, SECONDARY | SECONDARY | testing.a_b.upgrade_id | 9 | 100.00 |  |
| b_pb | ref | PRIMARY,fk_building_has_province_province1_idx,fk_building_has_province_building1_idx | PRIMARY | testing.b_b.building_id | 1026 | 100.00 | Using index |
| b | ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | testing.b_pb.province_id | 1 | 5.00 | Using where |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some composite indexes:

```
province:  INDEX(game_id, province_location_id,  province_id, current_time)
province:  INDEX(province_location_id,  current_time, province_id)
building:  INDEX(upgrade_id, building_id,  health)
province_has_building:  INDEX(province_id,  building_id)
```

If `province_has_building` is a "many-to-many mapping table", see [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for more speed-up tips.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.  That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I'm new to Mysql and generally learning about Indexes and implementing them meant a big performance improvement.

Comment: @zDox - Welcome to SQL and Stackoverflow.  A properly designed index can improve performance by orders of magnitude (in some cases).